# Active state in the wrong button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am editing a site that the menu is using a JavaScript. I managed to have it working but the hover state is just showing in the wrong place.

[Here is the link.](http://ryansemple.com) If you click on "Gallery" it's the Media that gets highlighted so on the last 3 menu items. Help please.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu .container').each(function(i){
    if(i==0)
    {
        var m = 1;  
    }
    else
    {
        var m = 2;
    }
    $(this).css('width',((m-1)*$(this).parent('li').height() + $(this).parent('li').width())).css('height',$(this).parent('li').height()).css('margin-left',-(m-1)*$(this).parent('li').height()).css('cursor','pointer');

    if(cur_page!=i)
    {
        $(this).find('.slide').html('<img src="' + tpl_base + '/images/menu-slide-' + (i+1) + '.png" />').css('top',$(this).parent('li').height()).css('left',-/*m**/($(this).parent('li').height()));
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find('.slide').html('<img src="' + tpl_base + '/images/menu-slide-' + (i+1) + '.png" />').css('top','0px').css('left','0px');
    }

    $(this).find('.text').html('<img src="' + tpl_base + '/images/menu-title-' + (i+1) + '.png" />').css('margin-left',(m-1)*$(this).parent('li').height());

    switch(i)
    {
        case 0: var a = url_base + '/bio';
            break;
        case 1: var a = url_base + '/blog';
            break;
        case 2: var a = url_base + '/gallery';
            break;
        case 3: var a = url_base + '/media';
            break;
        case 4: var a = url_base + '/contact';
            break;
        default: var a = url_base;
    }

    $(this).click(function(){
        window.location = a;                       
    });


    var t = $(this).parent('li').height();
    if(cur_page!=i)
    {
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.slide').stop().animate({top:'0px',left:/*-(t*(m-1))*/0 + 'px'}, 200)                    
        },function(){
            $(this).find('.slide').stop().animate({top:t + 'px',left:-(t/**m*/) + 'px'}, 400)                      
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: And if you click on Media Contact gets highlighted.. Check your html code, you have wrong classes on the menu items container. Media actially has 'gallery' class, etc.

Comment: I have change the classes but still no luck....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighting of the menu items appears to be done based on the variable cur_page which is being set incorrectly at some point in the code; here are the values as they sit now:

```
Home : cur_page = -1
Bio : cur_page = 0
Blog : cur_page = 1
Gallery : cur_page = 3 // Incorrect
Media : cur_page = 4 // Incorrect
```

I would check that this is being set correctly; good luck!

EDIT:

In the header of the Gallery page is this:

```
<script> 
    var url_base = "http://www.ryansemple.com";
    var tpl_base = "http://www.ryansemple.com/wp-content/themes/semple2010";
    var cur_page = -1;
    cur_page = 3;
</script>
```

Change it to this:

```
<script> 
    var url_base = "http://www.ryansemple.com";
    var tpl_base = "http://www.ryansemple.com/wp-content/themes/semple2010";
    var cur_page = 2;
</script>
```

A similar fix should take care of the remaining pages.

Answer (score 0):

What is `cur_page`? I assuming that it's current page index and you have difference in calculation. Probably your index starts with 0 but `cur_page` starts from 1.